# CSS Flexible Height with scrollable content

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a flexible width/height page layout with no window scrollbars!

Any content that will not fit on the page should be scrollable independently with the overflow property.

I've seen plenty of ways to construct flexible width layouts using just HTML and CSS.

The following site does a pretty good job on that front: http://ago.tanfa.co.uk/css/layouts/css-3-column-layout-v1.html

I wish to implement scrollable content within the 3 centre columns. The content should be scrollable not the column div.

e.g.

```
<div class="column">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>These</li>
        <li>Items</li>
        <li>Should</li>
        <li>Be</li>
        <li>Scrollable</li>
        <li>If</li>
        <li>They</li>
        <li>Exceed</li>
        <li>The</li>
        <li>Column</li>
        <li>Height</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So far if the list exceeds the window height it pushes the footer off page.

I'm not to bothered about it working on old versions of IE, although that would score bonus points!

Comment: The link you provided took me to a site with window scrollbars (ff3.6) :-/

Comment: yeah, that solution works for the width but not the height :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

[JSFiddle scrollable li](http://jsfiddle.net/QEr95/).

Not sure if you can effectively hide the scrollbar just with CSS and HTML.

Comment: Kinda, but the scrollable content height can't be declared in pixels. It should be limited by the parents height

Comment: Updated my fiddle, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/QEr95/1/.

Change the `.column` height and see if that's what you're after :)

Comment: Yes, thats the effect i'm looking for. However, the .column height needs to be 100% not a defined number of pixels.

The list items should be scrollable when the window size is smaller than the contents

Comment: Ok, then this is what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/QEr95/3/. Change the height of `.wrap` and see.

Comment: Sweeet! a bit of tinkering and we seem to have a solution.

I've created a new fiddle with the previously mentioned flexible width layout.

http://jsfiddle.net/xjWdN/

Thanks!